# Exp-resso store Payment order description

Tags: expresso-store

While I'm here I'll might ask the next question as well.

When placing and paying an order on the transaction description from the payment provider it only says "Order 12" or another number.

Is it possible to change this. For example by adding the product title or something else custom. One of the custom order fields perhaps?

I'm setting up Store to work with donations and a little shop. It would be nice to add something extra to the description like "Donation ..."

Running EE 2.5.5 and Store 1.6.3

Tnx, Martijn

Answer (score 1):

In your templates you can use the `{items}` loop to list out any additional details about a specific order that you want. Something along the lines of:

```
{exp:store:orders}
{items}
 {title} -- {item_subtotal}
{/items}
{exp:store:orders}
```

This will work in the Cart/Checkout/Orders templates and the email templates. You can use any variables mentioned [here](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/checkout_tag.html) along with a few extra tags in the order template/email listed [here](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/orders_tag.html)

Comment: Tnx Justin. But is it possible to send it to the payment privider transaction description. For example PayPal. Now it only states "Order" on PayPals' description.

Comment: The only way currently is to hack the PayPal Gateway files to change the text. There is a pull request to the CI-Merchant Library on GitHub that allows for product details to be passed over but has not been fully tested. You can see the pull request at https://github.com/expressodev/ci-merchant/pull/11